# how to call instagram api in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, instagram-api

I want to call instagram api in callback function but when i try to do it an error occured. "Headers alreay sent". I have registered my application on instagram developer. This is very basic thing but i'm new with api.

```
 function insta_plugin_menu(){
    add_menu_page( 'insta', 'Insta', 'manage_options', 'insta_slug',      'insta_callback_function','dashicons-admin-users',3 );
            }
    add_action('admin_menu','insta_plugin_menu');
    function insta_callback_function(){
    wp_redirect("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=af450e026f99441abf0d4dab66daf84c&redirect_uri=http://wsiserver.website/shahbaz/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=insta_slug&response_type=code");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call instagram API then `wp_redirect()` is probably not the best way to do. That function is used to redirect not for calling any api.

You are getting the error may be because of various reasons.

- You have to use `wp_redirect()` before `get_header()` Then it will not show header error.
- you're sending data to the browser before calling `wp_redirect()`

But ; You should try

```html
function insta_plugin_menu(){
 add_menu_page( 'insta', 'Insta', 'manage_options', 'insta_slug',      'insta_callback_function','dashicons-admin-users',3 );
}
add_action('admin_menu','insta_plugin_menu');
function insta_callback_function(){
 $url="https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=af450e026f99441abf0d4dab66daf84c&redirect_uri=http://wsiserver.website/shahbaz/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=insta_slug&response_type=code";
 
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_error($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 
 $result = json_decode($result);
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that.